# The close dialog is not fully visible (not centered vertically) on lower resolutions

Tags: bug, design

[image: Close dialog]

As you can see in the screenshot, part of the close dialog is cut off even though there's some space above it, meaning it could actually be centered and fit in the view.

**Environment:**

- OS: Windows 64-bit.
- Browser: Chrome v.73.0.3683.75 (64-bit).
- Screen resolution: 1366x768.

Note: Scrolling down (before or after clicking the close button) *is* an option but it would be better if we make use of the space above the dialog and make it centered by default.

Comment: Just scroll down to see the button and click it. 768px is a bit low for today's resolutions. Can't accomodate all possible screen resolutions. Scrolling seems like a very reasonable solution to me.

Comment: @yivi Yes, you can. But why is it not all visible/centered by default when there's plenty of space above it? I added a better screenshot which shows the full space above the dialog.

Comment: Centers fine for me (FF 65) when constrained to that resolution. It just doesn't overlap top-bar/title and won't use that space when available. That's only a problem on very short posts, else that's out of view anyway

Comment: Hover over it and you can drag and drop it anywhere ;)